# Accessing css/js files from another folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I downloaded a laravel source code and the css/js files that is used for the application is not stored in the public folder of the laravel application, instead it is stored in another folder called assets that is even outside of the application folder structure, and the files are accessed using the asset(), this is the structure;

- Files

  - assets

    - css
    - js
    - images
  - core

    - app
    - public

      - css

        - app.css
      - js

        - app.js
    - resources
    - routes
    - the remaining laravel folders and files
  - .htaccess
  - index.php
  - robots.txt
  - web.config

Now, the vendor of the source code said, 'on the Folder **assets**, we keep all kind of asset like **CSS,JS,Images**.so if you want to edit or change the application style have a look on this folder', while on the folder **'core'**, we keep the Core laravel application.

But my question is how do I use this same process in my own application?, do I just create a folder outside the laravel folder structure and put all the css/js files and then use the **asset()** to access the files in my application??

Comment: `asset` generates a URL, it doesn't technically have to do with assets ... the only things that are accessible besides your routes are files in `public` so a folder that is not in `public` is not accessible via a URL, so you are missing something here

Comment: I have checked but I still haven't found anything missing, everything is working perfectly with the way they did it

Comment: because they have you pointing the webroot at what is labeled as `Files` in your hierarchy, which means it isn't pointing to `public`

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: You can use the base_path() function that returns the base URL of your application. For example: you can use it in your blade file like this {{ "..\..\".base_path()."assets/css/style.css" }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the same process in your application place the index.php in the main directory and link the index.php in server.php file.

Server.php should be like this -

```
<?php 
$uri = urldecode(
parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/../index.php';
```

This should be your .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then the assets can be accessed using "{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}"

Comment: Thanks **Puneet**, when I linked my **server.php** it worked well, but in the source code that I downloaded, they did not link the **server.php**, it still remains thesame with the way laravel set it and everything is working fine even without them linking the server.php, they only edited the **index.php***, so how do I do this?? Or is there a secret method that the programmers used ??

Comment: Please Puneet, you told me to edit the **server.php** file in my laravel application to the index.php file, but in the source code that I downloaded, they did not edit the server.php file, in fact I deleted everything that was stored in the server.php file and the application still worked very fine, so how did they do it, because I had to edit the server.php in my own application

Comment: I can't say unless i see the source code. But i use the same methods as answered above in 2 of my products that are available at codester..